# Can any one help me with javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a table with items, price and quantity. I want to get the quantity by the user and then the user will click on the total cost and the total price will appear in the box right next to it. I want help with the javascript code for this. I am confused how to give class or id to these cells and write the javascript for it.

```html
   
 
<table width="300" border="2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3" ><tbody> 
  <tr><th scope="col">Menu </th> <th scope="col">Price</th> <th scope="col">Quantity</th> </tr>
  <tr> <td>Shirt</td> <td>$ 12.99</td> <td><input type="text"></td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>Jeans</td> <td>$ 10.99</td> <td><input type="text"></td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>Jacket</td> <td>$ 20.25</td> <td><input type="text"></td> </tr> 
</tbody></table> 
<div> 
  <input type="button" value="Total Cost"> <input type="text"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Wecome to Stackoverflow! Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), provide a useful question title and the essential source code that describes your problem. Asking "please write my code" is not well-received.

Comment: @Sean I have the HTML code. I am learning javascript, but I am confused how to use id and class in javascript.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I agree with Leon that you should read the guide how you should write a question, but here is something to get you started:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Price: <input type="text" id="price" value="">
Quantity: <input type="text" id="quantity" value="">

<button onclick="calcPrice()">Calculate</button>

Total cost: <input type="text" id="cost" value="">


<script>
function calcPrice() {
    var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

    var cost = price * quantity;
    document.getElementById("cost").value = cost;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By posting answers to questions that should not be answered, you encourage users to continue on that path.